# How to use patch method in Tosca Api

Tags: api, tosca

I am trying to update the value in API. I am using a patch method to update the value using postman. When I am using the same method in Tosca API, it is using a get method and provides the response value and values are not updating. Could anyone suggest to me how to use the patch method in Tosca API? I have given the parameters and am still unable to use update the value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4SFg.png)

Comment: Please put code as text, not image

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue. Simply selecting PATCH as a method should to the job. Maybe you could provide more information here on how to reproduce the issue.